# Material UI Autocomplete add item with multiple select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I tried out the Autocomplete example from Material UI. Its about an add option when entering a new value. Here is the link to the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-lgeju?file=/demo.js
What I am wondering about is that the value in the input isnt actually added to the options in this example so it doesnt actually work. Why is that so? Also I cant use it for multiple select, (via adding the property "multiple" to the Autocomplete) since this would produce a "TypeError
Cannot read property 'length' of null". Is there a way to make that work for multiple select?

Would appreciate any help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props) regarding `multiple` prop:

> If true, value must be an array and the menu will support multiple
> selections.

So just initialize your state as an array so that it *would* have the property `length` and is an array so that satisfies the condition I quoted above

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

for add item
top100Films.push(value)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).